# Is there a way to making my browser borderless

Tags: browser

I know this is not programming related directly, however, I was wondering if there is a way I can run my chrome browser or any browser borderless and pined on my desktop, but not in full-screen mode.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For such questions you can use superuser.com. I suggest you use Vivaldi browser and use CTRL+F11 ro you can check these: https://superuser.com/questions/1461803/firefox-or-chrome-auto-hide-ui